# No pages loading in Laravel 4

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

i can't get any pages loading on a default laravel installation on a default apache installation, as in, i haven't done much to configure it.

When i go to my domain i get the first laravel page 'You have arrived.'.. so i went ahead and made a test route:

`Route::get('about', function() { echo 'Hello World'; });`

when i go to domain.net/about or domain.net/about.php both say page cannot be displayed. When i check error logs:

> [Wed Jun 05 13:50:43 2013] [error] [client 123.456.12.9] File does not exist: /home/xxx/public_html/about
>
> [Wed Jun 05 13:50:57 2013] [error] [client 123.456.12.9] script '/home/xxx/public_html/about.php' not found or unable to stat

I'm using the default htaccess file and i've also tried the other version off the laravel website. Using apache 2.2, php 5.4 with mcrypt installed.. apart from that my apache configuration is pretty much default so i'm assuming it's missing something important.

I have checked that mod_rewrite is loaded and it is.

i tried going to /index which gives page cannot be displayed, if i go to /index.php i get the home page.

Comment: Well, `File does not exist: /home/xxx/public_html/about` means it doesn't get rewritten to the base file. Are you sure `.htaccess` files are read? (You need at least [`AllowOverride Fileinfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) OTOH)

Comment: life saver! The default ruleset was AllowOverride None, and wasn't being enabled at any point.

I added the following to my httpd.conf:<Directory /home/*/public_html/> AllowOverride All </Directory>

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing here is "public_html" is not correct.  By default laravel uses "public" as the folder name.

Look at your apache config (vhost) and make sure that is correct.

Comment: there are 2 options for the public folders. you can set DocumentRoot to the /public folder, or you can remove the public folder and put everything else outside of public_html. From the Laravel docs: Laravel is designed to protect your application code, and local storage by placing only files that are necessarily public in the public folder. It is recommended that you either set the public folder as your site's documentRoot (also known as a web root) or to place the contents of public into your site's root directory and place all of Laravel's other files outside the web root.